# Loop only shows last image of the loop

Tags: java

My for loop only shows the last image in the loop. It will change the image but the image will be the last image in the loop. Is there anyway i can fix this to show each image at a time?

The event handler is supposed to get random numbers and based on the the number it gets it should choose an image of a dice to put in the imageViewer. For the most part it does that but the problem is, i want it to simulating skipping through each of those random rolls at least 10 times before showing the final roll.

````
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class RollDice extends Application {
    
    //Fields
    private int rollNum;
    private int rollNum2;
    private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    private Button rollButton = new Button("Rol_l");
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView imageView2;
    private Image dice1; 
    private Image dice2;
    private Image dice3; 
    private Image dice4; 
    private Image dice5;
    private Image dice6;
    private Image view1[] = {dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6};
    private Image view2[];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        
        // Launch the application.
        launch(args);
        
    }

    
    ```
````

````
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    
    //Creating Image objects
    dice1 = new Image("file:die_1.png");
    dice2 = new Image("file:die_2.png");
    dice3 = new Image("file:die_3.png");
    dice4 = new Image("file:die_4.png");
    dice5 = new Image("file:die_5.png");
    dice6 = new Image("file:die_6.png");
    
    
    
    //Creating Image View Objects
    imageView = new ImageView(dice2);
    imageView2 = new ImageView(dice1);
    
    //Sets the width of the image view object
    imageView.setFitWidth(200);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView2.setFitWidth(200);
    imageView2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    
    //Sets Mnemonic for the roll button
    rollButton.setMnemonicParsing(true);
    
    //Sets Mnemonic for file menu
    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("_File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonicParsing(true);
    
    //Sets Mnemonic for exit option
    MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("_Exit");
    exit.setMnemonicParsing(true);
    
    //Action handler for rollButton
    rollButton.setOnAction(new rollButtonHandler());
    
    //Adding exit to file menu
    fileMenu.getItems().addAll(exit);
    
    //Adds the file menu to the menu bar
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu);
    
    //Lambda expression for exit 
    exit.setOnAction(event -> {
        
        primaryStage.close();
       
            });     
    
    exit.setOnAction(event -> {
        
        
        
        
    });
    
    
    //Creates a HBox and adds imageView objects to it
    HBox imageHBox = new HBox(10, imageView, imageView2);
    imageHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    //Creates a VBox and adds the HBOX and rollButton it 
    VBox mainVBox = new VBox(10, imageHBox, rollButton);
    mainVBox.setFillWidth(false);
    mainVBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    //Creates a border pane and adds menuBar to it
    //then the vbox to the center   
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
    borderPane.setCenter(mainVBox);
    mainVBox.setPadding(new Insets(50));
    
    //Creates and shows the scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Roll Dice");
    primaryStage.show();                
                
}

```
```
/******************************************************************
*                                                                 *
*                   Roll Button Action Handler                    *
*                                                                 *
******************************************************************/
````

```
    class rollButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            
             for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                 
                roll(); //Calls the roll method
                roll2(); //Calls the roll2 method
                    
                    //Responsible for the first dice
                    if (getRoll() == 1) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice1);
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll() == 2) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice2);                  
                    }
    
                    if (getRoll() == 3) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice3);                  
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll() == 4) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice4);                  
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll() == 5) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice5);                  
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll() == 6) {
                        
                        imageView.setImage(dice6);                  
                    }
                    
                    //Responsible for the second dice
                    if (getRoll2() == 1) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice1);
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll2() == 2) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice2);                 
                    }
    
                    if (getRoll2() == 3) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice3);                 
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll2() == 4) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice4);                 
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll2() == 5) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice5);                 
                    }
                    
                    if (getRoll2() == 6) {
                        
                        imageView2.setImage(dice6);             
                    }                           
                }                       
            }
        }
```

```
/******************************************************************
*                                                                 *
*                       Methods for randomizing                   *
*                                                                 *
******************************************************************/


        /**
         * Gets a random value and initialize it to the variable "rollNum"
         */
        public void roll() {
            
            Random rand = new Random();
            rollNum = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;      
        }
        
        /**
         * Gets a random value and initialize it to the variable "rollNum2"
         */
        public void roll2() {
            
            Random rand2 = new Random();
            rollNum2 = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;        
        }
        
        /**
         * Gets the value stored in "rollNum"
         */
        public int getRoll() {
            
            return rollNum;
        }
        
        /**
         * Gets the value stored in "rollNum2"
         */
        public int getRoll2() {
            
            return rollNum2;
        }
```

}

Comment: Yes, the last one will be displayed. What you are trying to achieve? It would be helpful if you provide the whole segment of the code.

Comment: i have updated the code